# Can't launch flutter project with custom launch file in iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to launch custom main_dev.dart file in flutter but it's not working.
I cannot launch the Flutter project in ios with a custom launch file.
It's working properly on Android

Please help me to fix it

I am trying this command:
`flutter run -t lib/main_dev.dart --flavor=dev`

[image]

flutter doctor response:
[image]

MacOS 13.2.1 (22D68), M2

Xcode Version 14.3 (14E222b)